# Data-Binding fails with "couldn't make a guess"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, androidx, android-studio-3.2

Since the update to Android Studio `3.2.0` I face the following issue:

> Execution failed for task ':mobile:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
>
> > couldn't make a guess for com.ACME.database.model.Order

also seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528437/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-couldnt-make-a-guess-for-com-exa), which hints for that "package-names must start with a lower-case letter".

... it seems alike, as if this `variable` assignment would be the cause:

```
<data class=".databinding.OrderFragmentBinding">
    <variable name="order" type="com.ACME.database.model.Order"/>
    ...
</data>
```

found: [New data binding compiler for binding classes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#preview-compiler), which does not explain the change in behavior.

**Q**: are such assignments also affected by that naming convention? I mean, is there any chance (beside changing the uppercase package-name) to make that data-binding v2 "guess"  work out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

these settings in the `gradle.properties` do enable the `androidx` data-binding compiler:

```
android.databinding.enableV2 = false
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = true
```

one can see that by the fetched package:

```
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler/3.2.0/databinding-compiler-3.2.0.pom
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler/3.2.0/databinding-compiler-3.2.0.jar
```

and it complains:

```
WARNING: The option setting 'android.databinding.enableV2=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'

WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'
```

most likely `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` would be required, in order to data-bind a `Fragment` with the default v2 data-binding compiler. this is also just a temporary solution - but still better than to revert to the v1 data-binding compiler.

---

**Update**:

Since `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0` the above workaround does not work anymore; One has to refactor the XML files. It works best when not adding any `class=""` attribute into the `<data />` tag - and also adding this tag into any existing `<layout>` tag. Duplicate `id` on data-bound `<include>` tags may also prevent the generation (the `id` has to be set on the `<include>` tag, not in the included layout).

Answer (score 41):

Its because of your class name or package name which use databinding. These classes( which use databinding) has to started with capital letter and packages started with lowercase.

Comment: This answer works for me, but the question is: Is there any way to keep the packages starting with capital letters?

Answer (score 16):

Had a similar problem. Solved by renaming the data class by starting with capital letters.

Comment: Very beautiful dude. You made me cry.. Thanks

Comment: Same here, I had solved with renaming to first letter caps :-(

Comment: I had done the same mistake naming package first letter as a capital now I refactored it to first letter small fixed the problem

Comment: And change the package naming to start with simple letters

Answer (score 9):

A case where you will run into this error:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="something"
        type=""/>
</data>
```

Empty type or undefined Type

Answer (score 5):

Same thing happening to me after updating to 3.2 (working application before the migration, and no code change)... then this "guess" issue even though I do have lowercase in the first letters of the package name!

```
<data>
   ...
   <variable name="rule" type="com.gta.viewmodels.vmRule"/>
   ...
</data>
```

So I "guess" your issue will still remain even after you update the package name (which is best practice anyways, given issues appear *every* single time I upgrade Android Studio!).

Anyway, I solved by downgrading the v2 databinding in *gradle.properties* (you'll get an "unsupported" warning, but just ignore it):

```
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

Looks like the Android Studio PG hasn't tested that well this assertion ([here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-32-canary-9-now-available.html)):

*`Data Binding V2 is now enabled by default and is compatible with V1.`*

Comment: thanks for the input, but found a better temporary solution. might refactor to `androidx`, because I have the outdated `support-v4` library under suspicion, which provided that `Fragment` class.

Comment: Great Answer! Today i also upgraded AS 3.2, and facing same issue, Illegal Arguments Exception “couldn't make a guess for”. Thanks @gtrevi.

Comment: @Dhiren my answer extends on this. while disabling data-binding v2 is not the answer, that is hiding the problem (I could as well as have reverted to build-tools `3.1.4`, with exactly the same effect). if it would have been the answer, I would have accepted it, instead adding another one.

Comment: I absolutely agree that mine is not a solution, but a quick workaround (as the other extension Martin suggested) just to bust Yet Another Build-Braking Change for whom "dares" to upgrade this IDE.

Both should be used temporarily to move forward while adapting to the new, instead of a big-bang refactoring or tool regression (therefore the least changes the better in my opinion).

The real problem is the Android Studio PG, when it claims that "Data Binding V2 is now enabled by default and is compatible with V1" whereas it is not, since you need to change your code!

Comment: @MartinZeitler you are using outdated `support-v4`, but I am not, i am using everything new, but still getting “couldn't make a guess”, by updaing AS 3.2.
as you said by disabling data-binding v2 is not the answer and that is hiding the problem, tell me what the correct solution for that ?

@gtrevi if its quick workaround or temporary solution, let me know what can i do to get a rid from this warning ?

`WARNING: The option setting 'android.databinding.enableV2=false' is experimental and unsupported.`

Comment: `android.databinding.enableV2 = false`
and
`android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = true`
I have added this 2 lines in `gradle.properties` file for a quick solution. but warnings still appeared.

Comment: @Dhiren both of these answers are workarounds, this one is switching back to v1 and mine is switching to v2 androidx; you need to clean your project and/or delete the build directory, to get rid of the previously generated data-bindings.

Comment: @MartinZeitler You mean I must have to switching to v2 androidX. to get rid from `couldn't make a guess` error in AS 3.2, and remove `android.databinding.enableV2 = false` from `gradle.properties` ?

Comment: @Dhiren, yes... that's what's in my point above: welcome to Android Studio upgrades. To get the rid of the warning, you need to move to the new, and if you want to know how and why, I'd ask the Android Studio PG (google forum) since they claim _V2 to be backward compatible with V1_, whereas it is not, and they haven't even provided migration guidance/support. I don't plan to move to androidX soon, but when I'll do, happy to support/post hints.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this issue because 
1.my viewmodel classes was not extended from BaseObservable

2. my package name starts with capital letter

Comment: any workaround for capital package names?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and it solved by changing the first letter of clickhandler class name to the capital 
I changed this: **clickHandler**
to this: **ClickHandler**
    com.packagename.android.activity.AddAddressActivity.**ClickHandler**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case nothing of the above works, check if the class type your referencing is in the same module or in a module on which the module where the xml is dependes.

Comment: The dependency tree is key. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was just a incorrect path in the type variable XML file

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="com.example.liberdade.caixa.CaixaListener" />
```

Answer (score 1):

All the directories must be in simple letters , otherwise this error arises

example

```
package com.saw1993.mrep.activities.products
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case I was using class name in small alphabets (propertyModel) should be (PropertyModel)

Answer (score 0):

rename your package to have all small letters, after changing my package from

"com.AmoTech.unischool"
to
"com.amotech.unischool"

, the errors disappeared and i was able to build without errors in android studio.
[image showing change of package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNlLv.png)

Answer (score -1):

If your package start capital letter change it to small it will fix the problem.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57684236/2227743).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it.