# Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent after AndroidX migration

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx

After migrating my whole project to android x I can't get it to compile anymore.

I get 100 of following errors:

```
e: M:\tmp\EverywhereLauncher\app\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\devWithoutTestWithAccessibilityDebug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDevWithoutTestWithAccessibilityDebug\out\com\my\app\databinding\ActivityMainBinding.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
```

I don't know where to continue.

I have two problems now.

- I only see 100 errors
- all errors are the same and are probably hiding the real error

What I tried:

- I have following in my projects `build.gradle` to increase the number of printed errors to 10000:

  ```
  gradle.projectsEvaluated {
          tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
              options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "10000"
          }
      }
  ```

  This always worked but in this case it does not increase the errors that are printed

Any ideas what I could do next?

**Additional**

- I use following

  ```
  android.enableJetifier=true
  android.useAndroidX=true
  ```
- I use android studio `3.2`, with kotlin `1.2.61` and `3.3.0-alpha01` gradle build tools
- I use the `3.3.0-alpha01` gradle build tools because I also use evernote `com.evernote:android-state` which does not otherwise - problem is explained here: https://github.com/evernote/android-state/issues/56

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489036/549372

Comment: thanks a lot, this did not solve my problem but I tried the old data binding again and this lead to less errors and I could find the real culprit because of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION - increase logged erros**

In the past, following was enough in the broject's `build.gradle` file:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile.class) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "10000"
    }
}
```

With kotlin, following will help:

```
afterEvaluate {
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("kotlin-kapt")) {
        kapt {
            javacOptions {
                option("-Xmaxerrs", 10000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**REAL ISSUE**

In my case I converted a class from java to kotlin with some fields like following:

```
@Arg
Integer someValue;
```

The converter created following:

```
@Arg
internal var someValue: Int? = null
```

The problem:

`internal` does not work with the annotation, so it failed, but the log only showed the data binding errors...

**Example project `build.gradle`**

https://gist.github.com/MFlisar/eca8ae6c2e6a619913ab05d503a4368f

Comment: how exact use afterEvaluate?

Comment: You need to put it into your PROJECTS build.gradle, I've created a basic example gist here: https://gist.github.com/MFlisar/eca8ae6c2e6a619913ab05d503a4368f

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this bug after updating to androidx, tried everything suggested in a few stack overflow posts, finally updating to gradle plugin 3.3.0-beta03 worked