# Unresolved DataBinding dependency after latest Android Studio Update 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-databinding

After the latest update to Android Studio, the DataBinding dependency is missing. I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.3.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

This is my app´s build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.soulfetch2"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
def acraVersion = '5.1.3'
implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acraVersion"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-dialog:$acraVersion"
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0"
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-rc02"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version" 
}
}
```

I tried adding these dependencies, but it had no effect.

```
implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.2'
```

Another question here was solved by adding these to the gradle.properties, but it lead to another additional error in my case:

```
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Any idea what I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS 3.3.2
Gradle 4.10.1
Plugin 3.3.2

I had the same problem and resolved it by doing the following:

Go to Project Non-Source Files and open the .idea libraries folder
Delete all of the databinding dependencies from this folder.

Rebuild your app and should be ok!

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened to me when I did the Gradle update, in version 3.3.2 of Android Studio. But it seems to me that Android Studio is not fully prepared for this update. So I returned the version of gradle to 3.3.1 and everything went back to work.

glideVersion = '4.8.0'

gradleVersion = '3.3.1'

Comment: It works, and thanks, but is there a way to know when the update will be ready for use?

Comment: Ah, the other answer worked for me, and I can use 3.3.2 with it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem starts when you have a minor error in your code (because of the upgrade to android x the R ids may be little changed)
so the preprocessor fails to interpret the code . and generate classes
then the class name guess function since 3.2.0 started to not work well.

and it results in the error: couldn't make a guess for com.PackageName.ClassName.(if you need the stacktrace below)

the problem is instead of com.PackageName.ClassName 
it guesses com.PackageName
I believe it searches for the first capital first letter and makes it a class

so the solution is to make package names to start with a lower case letter

I found the answer for this in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868381/466363
just changing the package names to lower case helped.

to do refactor efficiently:

the errors are for generated classes for layouts.

1. to make all packages a lowercase.
2. in every data binding layout.xml
3. in variables,
4. in type attribute,
5. right-click on the package name,
6. and click rename.
7. check two checkboxes. click ok.
8. click do refactor button.

the stack trace of could not guess package name:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.PackageName.ClassName 
    at com.squareup.javapoet.Util.checkArgument(Util.java:64)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.bestGuess(ClassName.java:177)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.toTypeName(ext.kt:244)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.toTypeName(ext.kt:192)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.toTypeName(ext.kt:173)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.createVariableFields(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:229)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.access$createVariableFields(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:39)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter$createType$1.invoke(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:67)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter$createType$1.invoke(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:39)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.Javapoet_extKt.classSpec(javapoet_ext.kt:39)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.createType(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:63)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.write(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:59)
    at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder.generateAll(BaseDataBinder.kt:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$CodeGenerator.run(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:212)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$writeBaseClasses$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:52)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$writeBaseClasses$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.writeBaseClasses(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it in these steps.

**1. Add kotlin "KAPT" plugin in build.gradle(app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

**2. Add this dependency and rebuild your app**

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc02"
```