# Data-Binding fails with "couldn't make a guess" ANDROID

Tags: debugging, data-binding

**Cause: couldn't make a guess for**

> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> couldn't make a guess for

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: You've not added much detail, but may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488520/data-binding-fails-with-couldnt-make-a-guess

Answer (score 0):

This is because of XML file Error maintained below ,

1. Check your **variable attribute** in **layout tag** it must not contain null
   value.
2. Check your **variable attribute** in **layout tag** your package name must not
   start with capital alphabet and Class name must not start with small alphabet.[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO9oB.png)